# typescript select/deselect all checkbox

Tags: typescript

I need a single select/deselect all check box in Typescript. The code below will select all when checked but will not deselect all when unchecked.

```js
selectAllLocations() {
  var selectAll = < HTMLInputElement > document.getElementById("allLocations");
  let locationElements: NodeListOf < Element > = document.getElementsByClassName("route-location-list");
  for (var i = 0; i < locationElements.length; i++) {
    if (selectAll.checked && (( < HTMLInputElement > locationElements[i]).checked == false)) {
      ( < HTMLInputElement > locationElements[i]).click();
    } else if ((!selectAll.checked) && ( < HTMLInputElement > locationElements[i]).checked) {
      ( < HTMLInputElement > locationElements[i]).click();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to click the checkbox in order to uncheck it. Just setting the `checked` property to `false` should work:

```
(< HTMLInputElement > locationElements[i]).checked = false;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't even select for me.